# Aggregating against rest of the values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I need help analyzing below data. The logic I need is sum of each provider should be divided by rest of the providers. For example based on below data each sum(provider) should be dived by sum( rest of providers)

```
sum(east RISK)/sum(west Risk)+sum(south RISK)
sum(west RISK)/sum(east RISK)+sum(south RISK)
sum(south RISK)/sum(east RISK)+sum(west RISK)
and so on....
....
....


Mbr Provider        Group           Risk
1   east            Group           2.44
2   east            Group           0.05
3   east            Group           1.01
4   east            Group           0.14
5   west            Comp MRKT       0.32
6   west            Comp MRKT       2.12
7   south           Comp MRKT       5.78
8   south           Comp MRKT       1.11
```

Comment: Please provide the input data, what you expect the output to be and what have you tried so far. Without these the questions makes no sense.

Comment: And tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which dbms???  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ANSI standard window functions for this purpose:

```
select provider,
       (sum(risk) / (sum(sum(risk)) over () - sum(risk))
       )
from t
group by provider;
```